# How to make WHERE clause case insensitive: From SQL Server querying Oracle linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, case-insensitive, openquery

We have a **MS SQL Server 2005** installation that connects to an **Oracle** database through a **linked server connection**.

Lots of SELECT statements are being performed through a series of `OPENQUERY()` commands. The WHERE clause in the majority of these statements are against `VARCHAR` columns.

I've heard that if the WHERE clause is case sensitive, it can have a big impact on performance.

So my question is, **how can I make sure that the non-binary string WHERE clauses are being performed in a case insensitive way for maximum performance?**

Comment: Is the basic objective to improve performance? First confirm you have a performance issue due to this (you probably don't) otherwise you could be introducing unnecessary code which in fact causes a performance issue. I believe the that what you 'heard' is a myth or a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually the other way around:

Case sensitive...

```
WHERE column = :criteria
```

...will use index on `column` directly and perform well.

Case insensitivity typically requires something like this...

```
WHERE UPPER(column) = UPPER(:criteria)
```

...which does **not** use index on `column` and performs poorly (unless you are careful and create a **functional** index on `UPPER(column)`).

I'm not sure whether `OPENQUERY()` changes anything, but from purely Oracle perspective both case-sensitive and insensitive queries can be made performant, with the insensitive ones requiring special care (functional index).

Comment: This is the most complete answer because it includes the caveat about poor performance with UPPER or LOWER and the use of a functional index. The other answers omit this and this can cause an unwelcome surprise on a live system with significant data.

Answer (score 4):

By default SQL server uses a case insensitive collation where Oracle is case sensitive by default.  For searches we normally implement the Upper() comparison to ensure the user has a better search experience.

Answer (score 2):

> I've heard that if the WHERE clause is case sensitive, it can have a big impact on performance.

From where did you hear that? Sounds like a myth to me... rather it would be other way around, ie if you'd use something like `WHERE lower(field) = 'some str'` to achieve case-insentive comparision it would be bad on perfomance. Using case-insensitive collation would probably be significantly faster...

Another important point to consider is do your business rules actually allow case-insensitive comparision.

And last but not least, you should start to optimize when you indeed do have a perfomance problem, not because you heard something...

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE LOWER(field_name) = 'field_value'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, TarasM! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solves. Please update your solution with an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand :)

Comment: Additionally, please note why you've added a new answer that looks completely like the existing ones

Answer (score 0):

To make `WHERE clause` case insensitive, you can use `LOWER` or `UPPER` for this purpose.

```
 select * from Table_Name
 where  lower(Column_Name) = lower('mY Any Value')
```

OR

```
select * from Table_Name
where  UPPER(Column_Name) = UPPER('mY Any Value')
```